# C# stream reader reading whitespaces and bypassing them

Tags: c#, streamreader

I am creating a program that reads a text file and gets the data then puts it into an array. My problem is that there are instances where a column is intended to be blank but the blank value must still be considered as a value but when my program reads the blank column, it reads the next value and puts it in the array where the value should be 0 or blank. I have tried to count the spaces between each column to make it a condition but the spaces are not reliable since the data varies in length. Any ideas about how I might do this?

Here is what my text data looks like.

```
Data1    Data2    Data3
1.325    1.57     51.2
2.2               21.85
         12.5     25.13
15.85    13.78    1.85
```

I need my array to look like this

```
firstRow['1.325','1.57','51.2'];
secondRow['2.2','0','21.85'];
```

Comment: It is highly unpredictable unless the column length is fixed or values are delimited by some character e.g. comma. If you have control over the file, try generating it with CSV format

Comment: Use your headers starting offset as columns absolute offset (each "D" of "Datax"), and distance between them as absolute column width. Then for each next line, you split using the substring function.

Comment: This is a tricky problem, if possible you would change the data to a csv format. However if this is all you have, you would need work out the maximum width of the column and work your way across

Comment: `the spaces are not reliable since the data varies in length` If there is no way to determine if a number of spaces represents a gap in the data or not, there is no way to do this.

Comment: Does the header always look like this `Data1    Data2    Data3` ?

Comment: It is not clear if you have a fixed length format or not. If all the lines have the same length then the Split method is not the correct one to use, instead you can easily count the length of each "column" and extract blocks of data with Substring from the whole line.

Comment: @TheGeneral no, its only a small part of the text file which I am having problem with

Comment: Does the header change? i mean, if you read this file tomorrow is the header going to be the same (exactly the same)

Comment: @TheGeneral if that's what you mean, yes.

Comment: Do the header column names have spaces in them. or to say it another way, are the column names always one word (no spaces)? If we can make some assumptions we can write a solution for this

Comment: @TheGeneral there are spaces in the headers but I must also say that the spaces between each header varies depending on the length of the header name

Comment: Cant you paste the header thanks and the first line of data into the question

Comment: If you have a list of headers and your data is always aligned to the headers then you may be able to do string slicing from the header positions.

Answer (score 0):

If your file is `tab`-splitted, use `line.Split("\t")` to get array of substrings of each line. Then, each substring you can convert into you data type. In your case it must be nullable, e,g, `decimal?`.

Comment: It's not tab splitted :(

Answer (score 0):

Here's a starting point if you have a list of headers in the order they appear in the data and if your values are always aligned to the headers.

```
import io, csv, sys

data = '''\
Data 1    Data 2    Data 3
1.325     1.57      51.2
2.2                 21.85
          12.5      25.13
15.85     13.78     1.85
'''

headers = ['Data 1', 'Data 2', 'Data 3'] # order should match headers

f = io.StringIO(data)
h = f.readline()
indexes = [h.find(s) for s in headers]
rows = []
for line in f:
    line = line[:-1] # strip trailing linefeed
    d = {}
    for key, index in list(zip(headers, indexes))[::-1]: # slice from the right
        val = line[index:]
        line = line[:index]
        d[key] = val.strip()
    rows.append(d)

writer = csv.DictWriter(sys.stdout, headers)
writer.writeheader()
writer.writerows(rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I have ran out of time, what I did was to count the number of spaces and if the spaces exceed by a number (in my case, 10) I'll add a value empty value in my array

```
string[] lsData = pData.Split(' ');
            string[] lsData1 = new string[18];
            int newArrayData = 0;
            int spaceCounter = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < lsData.Length; i++)
            {
                if (lsData[i] != "")
                {
                    lsData1[newArrayData] = lsData[i];
                    newArrayData++;
                    spaceCounter = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    spaceCounter++;
                }


                if (spaceCounter >= 10)
                {
                    lsData1[newArrayData] = "";
                    newArrayData++;
                    spaceCounter = 0;
                }
            }
```